# Does this linear map from $C^0(a,b) \rightarrow C^1(a,b)$ exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I came across this exercise in my linear algebra notes, and am unable to concretely get an answer:

> Is there a linear map $I:C^0(a,b) \rightarrow C^1(a,b)$ such that if $I(g) = f$, then $f' = g$?

On the surface, since we know that every continuous real-valued function is Riemann integrable, the proposition doesn't seem unreasonable. Furthermore, checking out the basic properties of a linear transformation
$$T(v+w) = T(v) + T(w) $$
$$T(\lambda v) = \lambda T(v)$$
doesn't appear to yield any obvious contradiction, since it is indeed true that $$\int(u+v) \mathrm{d}x = \int (u) \mathrm{d}x + \int (v) \mathrm{d}x$$
and that
$$\int (\lambda u)\mathrm{d}x = \lambda \cdot\int (u)\mathrm{d}x$$

So is this proposition true? I can't seem to find anything *against* it, but I can't find a definite proof either.

Comment: The existence of such a map would imply that $g$ has a unique antiderivative, no? But that certainly can't be the case because, for instance, we could take $I(g) = f+c$, with $c$ being a constant function, and this would certainly satisfy $(f+c)' = f' = g$.

Comment: It seems that $I$ can be defined as $I(g):=f$ where $f$ is a *particular* antiderivative of $g$: $f(x):=\int_a^x g(t)dt$.